# SSRS How to hide the entire subreport based on a multi value parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have 2 reports Report 1 (Main) and Report 2 (Sub-Report attached to Report 1). I have a multi value Parameter called Business - "COM" and "GOV".  The logic of the report are:

a.) If Business="COM" show "COM" report and hide "GOV" sub-report.
b.) If Business="GOV" show "GOV" report and hide "COM" main report.
c.) If Business is both "COM" and "COM" show both reports.

Note that each tablix is filtered by "COM" and "GOV"

**Visibility Expression**

```
=IIF(Join(Parameters!Business.Value,"")="GOV",True,False)
```

This expression is added in the rectangle box with the subreport inside.

**Issue**
1.) When Business="COM" it is not hiding the subreport so when exported to excel 2 tabs are visible COM with data and GOV without data but with visible header.

2.) When Business='GOV" it is hiding the COM report, but the excel tab name is not GOV it is COM.

There's no issue when both COM and GOV are selected. 
Does the visibility expression only work on non multi value parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit old.. but I had the same issue and have figured out how to do this..so this might help someone out there looking.

-What you want in the subreport visibility expression is something like this:

```
=IIF(Join(Parameters!Business.Value,",").Contains("COM"),false,true)

=IIF(Join(Parameters!Business.Value,",").Contains("GOV"),false,true)
```

play around with the above and you should arrive at your desired solution.. I know I did and it works like a treat. Good luck